# Get statistical informations about an Android device

Tags: android

I write an App and I'd like to get some informations about the Android devices my users are using.

I'd like to know

- manufactor
- the Android version
- and some kind of unique ID

Is that possible without any special permissions? What is the API?

Comment: You are going to need to be *much* more specific. In fact, it would probably be easier if you listed the "informations" you are interested in, and we can tell you which of those do not require any permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) object.  It will give you some details about the Android build.

Information about the Android version can be found in [Build.VERSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Do I need any permissions to access this?

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to know the manufactor, the Android version and some kind of
>   unique ID. Is that possible without any special permissions?

If you wrote 'permission' word in terms of manifest permission then you dont need any special permission for that , because its not something from user must be aware about application access of that data .

and if you would like to know about Build  information then brianestey's answer is much clear to that .